# backbone events not triggering in Safari

Tags: backbone.js

For a learning exercise I converted a sinatra/backbone app to the Rails environment.  I got it working on Chrome and Firefox but it doesn't work on Safari. It turns out that the original app  http://backbone-hangman.heroku.com doesn't work on Safari either. When you click "new game" it doesn't seem to fire an event.  The Safari console doesn't show any errors (although I'm not that experienced with Safari's developer tools as I never use them).

Since there is a live version of the app available here http://backbone-hangman.heroku.com  I won't post a lot of code, but this is the view code that sets an event on click #new_game, triggering the startNewGame function. Nothing happens in Safari. Source code for the original is here https://github.com/trivektor/Backbone-Hangman

I googled a bit and found some mention of Safari treating events differently but couldn't find a solution. Can any recommend anything?

```
$(function() {

  window.OptionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#options"),
    initialize: function() {
      this.model.bind("gameStartedEvent", this.removeGetAnswerButton, this);
      this.model.bind("guessCheckedEvent", this.showGetAnswerButton, this);
    },
    events: {
      'click #new_game': 'startNewGame',
      'click #show_answer': 'showAnswer'
    },
    startNewGame: function() {
      this.model.new();
    },
    removeGetAnswerButton: function() {
      $("#show_answer").remove();
    },
    showGetAnswerButton: function(response) {
      console.log("showGetAnswerButton");
      console.log(response);
      var threshold = this.model.get("threshold");
      console.log(threshold);
      if (response.incorrect_guesses == this.model.get("threshold")) {
        $(this.el).append('<input type="button" id="show_answer" class="action_button" value="Show answer" />');
      }
    },
    showAnswer: function() {
      this.model.get_answer();
    }
  })

})
```

Update

Based on one of the comments below the OP, I'm posting more code. This is hangman.js where the objects are instantiated

```
var game = new Game

  var options_view = new OptionsView({model: game});

  var characters_view = new CharactersView({model: game});

  var hint_view = new HintView({model: game});

  var word_view = new WordView({model: game});

  var hangman_view = new HangmanView({model: game});

  var answer_view = new AnswerView({model: game});
  var stage_view = new StageView({model: game});
```

The views and models are attached to the window like this

```
window.AnswerView = Backbone.View.extend({ ...
```

Update
Aside from Backbone, jQuery and Underscore which are loaded sitewide, the following files are loaded for this specific app in the Rails system.

[image]

Comment: This question seems odd to me: Backbone just uses jQuery (or Zepto, if you're in to that sort of thing) to do its event hookups, and jQuery is famous for handling browser issues for you.  Not that I'm calling you a liar or anything ;-)  Just saying, this question is very peculiar.

Comment: well, you can check the code in demo app yourself. Does it work for you in Safari?

Comment: Well does options even exist on pageload? could be something for document ready timing

Comment: Uh did you forget to new the object? new Window.OptionsView()? Could also be that your attaching it to window DIRECTLY, I wouldn't do that and just let the global be whatever. Not sure how Safari manages the global window before page load.

Comment: @amchang87  I updated the OP with more code based on my understanding of your comment. However, since I'm not that experienced, i'm uncertain of what changes might need to be made...Would you mind writing an answer showing how I might change the code so that I'm not "attaching it to window DIRECTLY"?  if that's indeed what I'm doing....Thanks

Comment: I recommend that you set it up on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com to make it easier for people to play with it, you don't need the whole thing, just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Try OptionsView = Backbone.View.extend({

Comment: @muistooshort  I'll try to set it up on jsfiddle.net but due to the fact that it loads in data, uses sessions etc, it seems complicated for me to replicate on fiddle ... the source code for the original (which also doesn't work for safari) is also available for donwload https://github.com/trivektor/Backbone-Hangman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is jQuery + Safari issue (document.ready)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311106/safari-jquery-compatibility)

You can just move your scripts inside the body tag and remove `$(function(){ /**/ })` wrapper in every file.

Also I added requirejs support and made [pull request](https://github.com/trivektor/Backbone-Hangman/pull/1)

## EDIT:

First of all sorry for my English :)

---

#### File views/index.haml:

We should embed js at the bottom of the page (to avoid Safari error)

`= javascript_include_tag  "javascript/require.js", :"data-main" => "javascript/config"`

Here `javascript/config` is the path to requirejs config.

---

#### File public/javascript/config.js:

`"deps" : ["hangman"]`

This means that application will start with `hangman.js`

---

#### File public/javascript/hangman.js:

We don't need `$(function() {` wrapper because our script initialized from the body and document is already 'ready'

```
define([
  'models/game',
  'views/answerView',
  /* ... */
],
function(Game, OptionsView, /* ... */) {
  // ...
}
```

Here we load our modules (first array element will be available in the first function argument and so on)

---

#### Other files

We just replace `$(function() {` with `define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {`

In the first line we load backbone module. When it will be fetched it will be available inside anonymous function (first parameter - Backbone)

Next we should return the view to avoid `undefined` module value (`public/javascript/hangman.js` file should initialize a lot views. It can't initialize `undefined` it should initialize `Backbone.View` that we should return)

---

To learn more you should read requirejs documentation.
I recomend you to start with [this article](http://jspro.com/toolsandlibraries/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/)

Comment: that's not my github account so I can't accept the pull request but i'll try to duplicate it on my code. I've looked at require.js docs before and got confused setting it up. Can you please briefly explain in plain language what you did in each file (if you have time), so that I can duplicate this on other projects.

Comment: @Michael no problem, look above

Comment: thanks, I downloaded your code and tried it in Safari. It starts. The lines for the word that needs to be guessed is visible, but the actual letters the user clicks on to make a guess aren't showing, although they are visible in Chrome. Is this expected? Did you only partially implement require.js?

Comment: Oh... This Safari :) `this.el.show()` doesn't work properly. I changed it to `this.el.css('display','block')` and now all works fine https://github.com/vermilion1/Backbone-Hangman/commit/b081efc032191dbb52bd442e5b0da4a0654df149

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
var OptionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#options"),
    initialize: function() {
      this.model.bind("gameStartedEvent", this.removeGetAnswerButton, this);
      this.model.bind("guessCheckedEvent", this.showGetAnswerButton, this);
    },
    events: {
      'click #new_game': 'startNewGame',
      'click #show_answer': 'showAnswer'
    },
    startNewGame: function() {
      this.model.new();
    },
    removeGetAnswerButton: function() {
      $("#show_answer").remove();
    },
    showGetAnswerButton: function(response) {
      console.log("showGetAnswerButton");
      console.log(response);
      var threshold = this.model.get("threshold");
      console.log(threshold);
      if (response.incorrect_guesses == this.model.get("threshold")) {
        $(this.el).append('<input type="button" id="show_answer" class="action_button" value="Show answer" />');
      }
    },
    showAnswer: function() {
      this.model.get_answer();
    }
  });
```

Your code dosen't need to be in a document ready (it's not directly manipulating DOM, it's just declaring an object);

Make sure game.js goes after all your declarations though.

It looks like a problem Safari has in adding variables to the Global Object. Using var in the global context makes sure window.OptionsView exists. You might want to consider using require.js in the future to manage all of these global object problems.

Comment: Changing 'window' to 'var' didn't fix the problem (I did it on all the views and the model. I  updated the OP with a snapshot of all the files being loaded for this app. Would you be able to add a few lines to your answer explaining how i might use require.js to fix this.

Comment: You need to remove the $() wrapper .... also the point literally was to paste the whole code I pasted in your file

Comment: Can you explain why Game.js had to go after all the declarations? thanks if you can.